# Arc Hydro Stream WSE to point WSE measurement tool

Tags: arc-hydro

I wish to use stream wse to point measurement tool for finding out the flood inundation extent.

Can anyone provide an example of the input time series table to be used in the tool?

Comment: were you able to solve this? Please provide answers if possible. I am stuck doing same thing 5 years later :D